# Android Share via Gmail - a href tags missing

Tags: android, html

I want to share the below code via email. I was able to see the hyperlink for the URL earlier. But Currently, I am unable to click the link. Its just a plain Text in the Gmail Application.

```
String text = "<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\"></a>";      
Log.d("Share","Video : "+text);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     Html.fromHtml(text));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_mail)));
```

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown below.

```
String link_value = "www.google.com"
String body = "<a href=\"" + link_value + "\">" + link_value+ "</a>"
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

Comment: String body = "<a href=\"" + link_value + "\">" + "Click Here"+ "</a>" . I want to have Click Here to be Hyperlinked.

Comment: Click Here is not hyperlinked. Just a plain text

Comment: If i use the code you had shared, www.gooogle.com is hyperlinked. I want www.google.com to be named.

Comment: what do you mean by this "named" ? I want www.google.com to be named

Comment: Upon Clicking, "CLICK HERE" should open www.google.com. Basically, I want CLICK HERE to reference www.google.com

Comment: String clickhere = "clickhere"; String body = "<a href=\"" + link_value + "\">" + clickhere+ "</a>"

Comment: clickhere is a plain text. There is no hyperlink to click.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define html tag.
try this one,

```
String text ="http://www.w3schools.com\";      
Log.d("Share","Video : "+text);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     text));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_mail)));
```

Comment: Just a plain text is being displayed. Hyperlink still missing.